# ONLY non-relativistic limit of general relativity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, newtonian-gravity, approximations

From my study of GR I learnt that to reach the “Newtonian” limit of the Einstein field equation we have to assume:

1. weak field $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + \epsilon h _{\mu\nu}$ with $\epsilon << 1$
2. non-relativistic limit $c \to \infty$

My question is: what does it happen if we only perform the non-relativistic limit (2)? Which kind of equation comes out?

Comment: Non-relativistic limit is $c \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory

Comment: You'll also find that different components of $h_{\mu\nu}$ scale with $1/c^k$ (to some power $k$) such that $h_{00}$ ends up being the only component that survives in the limit $c\rightarrow \infty$ and ends up corresponding to the Newtonian potential.

Comment: You will get some rather interesting and useful results, unfortunately this approach does not seem to have caught on - I feel sure there is more to be learned this way: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/einstein/node10.html

Answer (score 4):

> … what does it happen if we only perform the non-relativistic limit … ?

You would get non-relativistic gravity theory, but one that would allow description of effects associated with *strong gravity* regime. It can be formulated using [Newton–Cartan geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory). Effects different from purely Newtonian theory (which also could be formulated using Newton–Cartan geometry but with additional constraints imposed) are:

- torsionful connection (there is a specific variant, *twistless torsion* leading to the usual galilean causality but with position-dependent time dilation);
- purely spatial (Ricci) curvature;
- spatially inhomogeneous Coriolis fields, which allow descriptions of such effects as rotational frame-dragging.

**References**

1. Van den Bleeken, D. (2017). *Torsional Newton–Cartan gravity from the large c expansion of general relativity*. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 34(18), 185004, [doi:10.1088/1361-6382/aa83d4](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/aa83d4), [arXiv:1703.03459](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03459).
2. Hartong, J., Obers, N. A., & Oling, G. (2022). *Review on Non-Relativistic Gravity*. [arXiv:2212.11309](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11309).